# testing accelerometer in android

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm working on an Android project that uses the accelerometer feature of tablets. I'm now slightly at the beginning of this project, so there is no objection to find the solution of my complaint. The question is, I have no android device right now and I want to test the sensitivity or directions of my accelerometer. As you know, there is no such a feature in android emulators. How can I test these sensors and events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this to emulate sensor data in the emulator:
http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Answer (score 1):

The `SensorSimulator` allows to Simulate the accelerometer in you emulator with the mouse actions.

Just download the and install it from [This](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) link.